# Animate elements on scroll using framer motion only when they enter the viewport

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am using the below custom hook to animate elements on scroll

```
import { useAnimation, useInView } from "framer-motion"
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

export const useAnimateOnScroll = (inView) => {
  const parentRef = useRef(null)
  const control = useAnimation()

  const isInView = useInView(parentRef, {
    once: false,
    amount: inView,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInView) {
      control.start("visible")
    } else {
      control.start("hidden")
    }
  }, [isInView, control])

  return {
    parentRef,
    control
  }
}
```

It works fine, however I want the elements to animate only when they enter the viewport and not when they leave. I tried removing

```
else {
      control.start("hidden")
    }
```

but it makes the animations happen only once (for the first time only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, you can use `getBoundingClientRect` to check elements' size and position relative to the viewport and trigger "hidden" animation accordingly. Now below hook will animate elements only when they enter the viewport.

```
import { useAnimation, useInView } from "framer-motion"
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react"

export const useAnimateOnScroll = (inView) => {
  const parentRef = useRef(null)
  const control = useAnimation()

  const isInView = useInView(parentRef, {
    once: false,
    amount: inView
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!parentRef.current) {
      return
    }
    if (isInView) {
      control.start("visible")
    } else {
      const { bottom } = parentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
      const isBelowScreenBottom = bottom > window.innerHeight
      if (isBelowScreenBottom) {
        control.start("hidden")
      }
    }
  }, [isInView, control])

  return {
    parentRef,
    control
  }
}
```